# link in a file by way of hard link into a directory using the files inode number

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am building a backup system that minimises space usage by identifying files with the same content and then hard linking files that have the same content together.

To achieve this I keep an index of file hashes and inode numbers. Looking at the documentation I can only see ways of linking files using path names and not inode numbers.  How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean to create soft links between files by their inode numbers?
can you add an example of what have you done so far and what you want to do please

Comment: I think I have come up with another way of doing this.

Comment: would you be able to share please

Comment: Store the file using its hash as a filename in a reference directory. Then can build the backup structure using standard link commands.  It leaves the problem of deleting the reference copy when it is the only one left, that could be done by a fuse file system as an intermediate to check reference count, a stacking file system to do the same, or as a batch job, or as a background task.

Comment: I am going to put several comments here because this is long.  And I think unavoidably so.

Comment: In order to link hard link there must be a copy of the file somewhere already. It could be a reference copy, or another backup copy. If it is a backup copy when the last backup copy is deleted the file disappears. Great. However with this approach we need to store the inode number and link to that (as per the original question). This is because the file path that originally stored the file may get deleted but the file still exists in later backups, and will be used again in still later backups.

Comment: You can post it as an answer instead of comments if it solved your problem :)

Comment: There exists in the FUSE low level library a function that will hard link a file with the inode number of the file, the inode number of the directory to put it in, and the name to give it in that directory.  So this is solution 1, build a FUSE file interface.

Comment: Possible solution 2 already outlined is to have a fixed reference copy and clean the mess up later.

Comment: Possible solution 3 is to find a filename from the inode number and then link using that filename.  Not sure how to do this yet.

Comment: have you tried btrfs to resolve inode to file? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35292/quickly-find-which-files-belongs-to-a-specific-inode-number

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using btrfs.  Worth a go.  I will try it.